# Script for take rate from website to write to .txt file

Tags: javascript, java

I don't know how to take BTC rate from this website
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=9  (7th row "price_usd")
to use it for some calculation and then write it to .txt file.

I already used it, calculated a screen it on my website by javascript, but I can't write it to txt file in my PC and I need it. I know that javascript doesn't offer to write it to .txt file, but do you have any idea how to do it with writing to txt file by different language?

Comment: Well it can if you run node on your local machine.. Is there a reason you tagged this Java which is unrelated to JavaScript?

Comment: yes, because I was asking about other languages.... by the way, I have no idea what do you mean with running node on my local machine...

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moe, you can use bash scripting on linux (if you are familiar). Here is the code. This should give you a direction to perform your calculations. Try running this from the command line. You can still simplify this code.

```
wget "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=9" -O output

cat output | grep 'price_usd' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's/price_usd//g' | sed 's/: //g' | awk '{print $1}' >
final.txt

cat final.txt
```

Comment: Moe, I tried changing the limit to 1 on the link and it still works fine. This is my result from cat final.txt --- 3457.00990708

Comment: yeap Im sorry I already deleted my comment, because when I wrote second time that command  I deleted inadvertently one mark and it was still using website from the first command with number 9 :D

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help. On the other note - they do have some historical crypto data which you can extract using the same method. https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20170101/ which you can extract and import into database and do your data analysis...

Comment: I try to put 3 letters BTC behind the number and it doesnt work... When I put it in command before number it works... I have been trying it almost 2 hours and still nothing... do you know where excatly I should put the BTC with all marks of course

Comment: Moe, are you referring you my previous comment on historical data or are you referring to my answer...I am happy to help but dont know what you referring to...let me know